# Is Linear kernel SVM always better than Logistic regression?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression, svm, linear-models

We know that [linear kernel SVM may give better results than logistic regression](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Ftowardsdatascience.com%2Fsvm-feature-selection-and-kernels-840781cc1a6c&psig=AOvVaw0qN0P-CkhzK7zmdDu5CEM6&ust=1672830533710000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CBAQjRxqFwoTCIi17r-hq_wCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAE) since maximizing the margin usually leads to more stable results/better displacement of the decision boundary. But is there any scenario in which a linear kernel SVM performs *worse* than a logistic regression with respect to test accuracy?

Comment: Define "better"/"worse".  By what metric?

Comment: As written, with respect to test accuracy, meaning that lower test accuracy results in worse results

Answer (score 2):

SVM may perform worse than Logistic Regression when the dataset is small, thus data points near the decision boundary (Support Vectors) may not be a true representation of the actual decision boundary, and thus may form a false maximum margin classifier boundary. 
I don't have any dataset example in mind but theoretically, that should be it